# Property Value Not Being Saved

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, properties

I have a property in one of my view controllers. I set the value in another view controller like so:

```
iDBArticleViewController *ArticleViewController;

if (ArticleViewController == nil)
{
    ArticleViewController = [[iDBArticleViewController alloc] init];
}


ArticleViewController.bannerIsVisible = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
[ArticleViewController layoutForInterfaceOrientation:orientation];
```

When the method layoutForInterfaceController: is called, the debug console prints out 0 just as I set the property for iDBArticleViewController. When I call the same method again in another place, the debug console prints out that the property bannerIsVisible is nil. Could the problem be because I am calling the method in another place in my code without setting the property again? I expected the property to not be set to nil. Shouldn't the property keep it's value? I initialize the property like so: `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *bannerIsVisible;`

Comment: It shouldn't be nil, but it's hard to tell what's going on without knowing where you're calling this method, and where the code you posted is. You need to make it clear what classes things are in.

Comment: could it be because i initialize the the iDBArticleViewController in the code above and when a button is pressed?

Comment: I have no idea -- you need to better explain the structure of your app. What classes are there? What class is the posted code in? In what class are you calling the method?

Comment: here is the code from BannerViewController http://pastie.org/5430173. The method from iDBArticleViewController is http://pastie.org/5430174. This method is called from BannerViewController and from iDBNewsViewController. The method from NewsViewController that open iDBArticleViewController is http://pastie.org/5430180. This is the code involved in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"When I call the same method again in another place, the debug console prints out that the property bannerIsVisible is nil."

If you are calling the same method in some other class, with same codes, then probably you are creating a new instances of ArticleViewController and its bannerIsVisible will be nil.

If you want to use same instance and its value throughout you can opt for a shared instance / singleton class.

Comment: I think that is what is happening. So I now need to initialize the class only once throughout the application using a singleton so the value of the property value did not change. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Mr.Russian : This mistake is done by everyone, even I did it when I started learning cocoa :)    And SO is here for help.

Comment: yeah sorry. i am pretty new to SO so i am learning how it works ;)